# Spring MongoDB Some fields are not being saved nor updated at all

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, nosql, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to save a document in `MongoDB` collection via `MongoRepository.save` method. Here's my code.

The document class:

```
   @Document(collection = "appointments")
   public class AppointmentDocument extends AbstractCommonDocument {
       @Id
       private ObjectId _id;
       @DBRef(lazy = true)
       private ServiceDocument service;
       @DBRef(lazy = true)
       private FeedbackDocument feedback;
       private String status;
       private String appointmentType;
       private String description;
       private EmbeddedPeriod period;
       private EmbeddedPeriod requestedPeriod;
       @Deprecated
       private ProviderFeedback providerFeedback;
       private List<Participant> participants;
       private List<AppointmentResponse> appointmentResponses;
       @Deprecated
       private AppointmentPayment paymentDetails;
       private CommunityPayment prePayment;
       private CommunityPayment postPayment;
       private boolean requestedByPatient;
       @Deprecated
       private DateTime acceptedAt;
       private DateTime requestedAt;
       private DateTime confirmedAt;
       private DateTime cancelledAt;
       private DateTime completedAt;
       private String requestMessage;
       private String mondayId;

       ...getters & setters
   }
```

The repository:

```
@Repository
public interface AppointmentRepository extends MongoRepository<AppointmentDocument, String> {
    
}
```

Code for saving record.

```
    AppointmentDocument appointmentDocument = new AppointmentDocument();
    
    // ...omitted set calls for other fields for brevity
    appointmentDocument.setRequestedByPatient(!isProvider);
    appointmentDocument.setRequestedAt(requestedAt);
    appointmentDocument.setRequestMessage(request.getComment());
    appointmentDocument = appointmentRepository.save(appointmentDocument);
```

The problem is that all the fields are getting saved inside the database except `requestedAt` and `requestMessage` field. There are no error logs, I've enabled the `MongoDB` logs and it appears to be sending the insert query with all the fields present there.

```
DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - 2021-04-21 19:22:58 - Inserting Document containing fields: [service, status, period, requestedPeriod, participants, appointmentResponses, prePayment, requestedByPatient, requestedAt, requestMessage, createdAt, lastModified, _class] in collection: appointments
```

Still I see that `requestedAt` and `requestMessage` is missing from the document in database.

I also tried updating the record after saving the document via `mongoTemplate.updateFirst` method. Still no luck. Here's the code for that.

```
    mongoTemplate.updateFirst(
                new Query(where("_id").is(appointmentDocument.get_id())),
                new Update()
                        .set("requestedAt",requestedAt)
                        .set("requestMessage", request.getComment()),
                AppointmentDocument.class
        );
```

Again I see logs for updating..

```
DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - 2021-04-21 19:22:58 - Calling update using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "60807b92adbe1d0001c2bed6" } } and update: { "$set" : { "requestedAt" : { "$date" : 1619032978091 }, "requestMessage" : "Dummy Request message" } } in collection: appointments
```

Still no luck. I got no clue why this is happening. Please help.

Comment: What are the values in the input fields `requestedAt` and `request.getComment()`?

Comment: @prasad_ `requestedAt = DateTime.now();` and `request.comment` is "Dummy Value"

Comment: Your repository has: `MongoRepository<AppointmentDocument, String>`. But your @Id field is of type `ObjectId`. What is `AbstractCommonDocument`? Did you try `insert` method instead of `save`?

Comment: @prasad_ `ObjectId` and `String` are interchangeable and we're using it since a long time without any issues. `AbstractCommonDocument` is an abstract class with some audit fields that are not concerned with the problem. I've shared the code and used `save` method